# How to set legend in seaborn to be automatic adjust with a standardize format

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

How do i adjust the chart legend in the picture?, i want the number to be in custom format such as
[5,000,000 | 10,000,000 | 15,000,000] or [5m | 10m | 15m] or [0.5 | 1.0 | 1.5]

```
plt.figure(figsize=(8,4), dpi=200)
 
# set styling on a single chart
with sns.axes_style('darkgrid'):
  ax = sns.scatterplot(data=data_clean,
                       x='USD_Production_Budget', 
                       y='USD_Worldwide_Gross',
                       hue='USD_Worldwide_Gross',
                       size='USD_Worldwide_Gross')
 
  ax.set(ylim=(0, 3000000000),
        xlim=(0, 450000000),
        ylabel='Revenue in $ billions',
        xlabel='Budget in $100 millions')

plt.show()
```

[Chart 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFcPl.png)

So far, i was able to find a work around but i would have to do it manually, which i would like to avoid

```
plt.figure(figsize=(8,4), dpi=200)
 
# set styling on a single chart
with sns.axes_style('darkgrid'):
  ax = sns.scatterplot(data=data_clean,
                       x='USD_Production_Budget', 
                       y='USD_Worldwide_Gross',
                       hue='USD_Worldwide_Gross',
                       size='USD_Worldwide_Gross')
 
  ax.set(ylim=(0, 3000000000),
        xlim=(0, 450000000),
        ylabel='Revenue in $ billions',
        xlabel='Budget in $100 millions')

plt.legend(title='World_Wide_Gross',loc='upper left',labels=[0,0.5,1.0,1.5,2.0,2.5])
plt.show()
```

[Chart 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyQIO.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [`FuncFormatter`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter) to customize the [*Text*](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text)s returned by [`get_texts`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/legend_api.html#matplotlib.legend.Legend.get_texts) of the original legend :

```
f = lambda x, _: "0m" if x == 0 else f"{x / 1e8:.0f}m" # / 1e6 would make more sense ?
#f = lambda x, _: 0 if x ==0 else x / 1e9 # uncomment this line to choose the 2nd format

fmt = plt.FuncFormatter(f)
    
for text in ax.legend().get_texts():
    text.set_text(fmt(float(text.get_text())))

ax.legend().set_title("World_Wide_Gross")
```

Output :

[image]

*Input used :*

```
np.random.seed(123456)

data_clean = pd.DataFrame({
    "USD_Production_Budget": np.random.uniform(0, 4.5e8, 100),
    "USD_Worldwide_Gross": np.random.uniform(0, 3e9, 100)}
)

data_clean.loc[5] = 0
```

Comment: **NB**: This code should be inserted inside the *context manger*: `with sns.axes_style('darkgrid'):`